# Usage of sound /ʒ/ in English (not /dʒ/)

Tags: pronunciation, consonants

I'm trying to explain to an English speaker how to pronounce the letter *j* in French, and was looking for cases where it appears in English. It seems that *j* is almost always pronounced /dʒ/. Examples of the /ʒ/ without /d/ in English are very rare: Asia, vision (many words ending in -sion), measure. In those words the vowel after /ʒ/ is always the same.

Where else in English does this consonant appears?

Comment: This question is just asking for a list. It is not constructive, for that reason.

Comment: Related: [Are “zh” and “j” pronounced in the same way?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12262/zh-vs-j-are-these-pronounced-in-the-same-way). Which is to say: look out for all the possible spellings! The answers to that question mention *Zhivago*, *beige*, *lesion*, *Jacques*...

Comment: It might be better to rephrase your question to get at the heart of your problem (teaching people to pronounce j in French) and ask it on [French Language and Usage](http://french.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Matt Эллен: I don't think so, because I'm looking for cases where this sound appears in the English language. But I will rephrase the question a bit.

Comment: Isn't what you are looking for quite like the English soft ***g***? In which case, you could look at words with the soft ***g***.

Comment: This question might be interesting for you :D http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57252/how-to-spell-d-and-what-does-it-mean

Answer (score 2):

The /ʒ/ sound only occurs initially in loan words, normally from French, such as *Gillet*. But the following vowel sound in this instance is different from *measure* and *vision*.